# ¿Cómo divido una lista con una serie de rangos específicos?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo una sección de mi código referente a la codificación de Penrose donde obtengo una lista como la siguiente:

`Laux=['R', '1', '1', 'R', 'R', '1', '0', '1', 'R', '1', '1', '0', 'L', '1', '0', '1', 'R', '1', 'STOP', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'L', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'L', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'L', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'R', '1', '0', '1', 'R', 'R', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'R', '1', '1', '1', 'R', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'R']`

Lo que quiero es dividir cada sub-lista que está delimitada con las letras, tengo una lista que me arroja donde se deben hacer las divisiones

```
clist=[0, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38, 42, 43, 48, 52, 57]
```

Donde lo que quiero es sacar de la lista `d`, `L2.append(d[0:3])` y después `L2.append(d[3:4])`, y así consecutivamente, con los rangos de `clist`, la parte del código es la siguiente:

```
for n in range(len(clist)):
    C2 = clist[n]
    C1 = clist[n-1] #Esta asi por que da errores al tener n+1

    print(C1)
    print(C2)
    print(Laux[C2:C1])

    S = Laux[C2:C1]
    print(S)
    L2.append(S)
    S = 0

    print("L2N es ", L2)
```

Pero a la salida el valor de `S` no se guarda, he intentado varias maneras, igual acepto propuestas quizá hay una manera más fácil que teniendo una lista con los rangos.

Comment: En primer lugar la lista `laux` no tiene subsista, tiene elementos. Lo que quieres es coger los elementos de esta lista en base a los números que tienes en la lista `clist`, no?

Comment: `C2:C1` están intercambiados. Primero debería ir `C1` y luego `C2` . Además tu `for` debe hacer una iteración menos. Ya sea empezar en `1` o terminar en `len(clist) - 1` y ajustar los indices acorde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se que esperas obtener de la variable `S` pues su valor lo estas guardando en la lista `L2`, otra cosa es que no es necesario volver a *formatear* el valor de esta variable, pues en cada iteración del ciclo esta ira adoptando el valor que tenga tu lista, por ultimo tu código esta bien solo que para hacer `[n+1]` tendríamos que decirle que itere en el rango de la longitud de la lista `-1`, quedando asi:

```py
L2 = []#aqui se almacenaran los valores

for i in range(len(clist)-1): #iteramos como dijimos
    c = clist  #renombramos la variable, es solo para no escribir tanto
    S = Laux[c[i]:c[i+1]] #obtenemos los datos
    L2.append(S) #agregamos los datos a la lista

print(L2) #imprimimos los datos
```

**Resultado**

```
[
['R', '1', '1'], ['R'], ['R', '1', '0', '1'], ['R', '1', '1', '0'], 
['L', '1', '0', '1'], ['R', '1'], ['STOP', '1', '0', '0', '0'], 
['L', '1', '0', '1', '1'], ['L', '1', '0', '0', '1'], ['L', '1', '1', '0', '0'],
['R', '1', '0', '1'], ['R'], ['R', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
['R', '1', '1', '1'], ['R', '1', '1', '1', '0']
]
```

Espero que sea lo que quieres, de lo contrario dímelo y tratare de ayudarte :).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo :)

Comment: de nada , es un placer ayudar :)